# Object wont update

Tags: django, model, methods, save

Hay all, my object doesnt seem to update when i call the save() method

heres my code

```
    car = Car.objects.get(pk=car_id)
    car.views += 1
    car.save()
```

and the model

```
views = models.FloatField(max_length=1000)
```

I do have a save() override method, could this cause a problem?

```
def save(self):
    d = timedelta(days=self.expires_in)
    if not self.id:
        self.expires_on = datetime.now() + d
        super(Car, self).save()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error in your code. It calls the superclasses `save` method only in case the object doesn't have an id yet. Fixed your code:

```
def save(self):
    d = timedelta(days=self.expires_in)
    if not self.id:
        self.expires_on = datetime.now() + d
    super(Car, self).save() # <-- here
```

Comment: +1 but check the docs for overriding save specifically:
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):


super(Car, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

From the docs:
It's also important that you pass through the arguments that can be passed to the model method -- that's what the *args, **kwargs bit does.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods

Answer (score 1):

Right now, it seems like your code will not go into the "if" block (unless the id is None), so the superclass's "save" method isn't getting called.